# EJB3.1 NotSerializableException

Tags: ejb, serializable

I am getting this error and i don't know how to fix:

> java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.procc.dao.**EJB31_Generated_*AlertFacade*_Intf_***Bean*_  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1362)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1170)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1100)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:325)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:173)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

this is AlertFacade:

> @Stateless public class AlertFacade extends AbstractFacade {
>       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "flams_pu")
>       private EntityManager em;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
>     return em;
> }
>
> public AlertFacade() {
>     super(Alert.class);
> } }
> ```

which i use in a JSF Managed bean.

is the EJB supposed to be Serializable ? I don't get it.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and add to the class signature `implements Serializable`. Since it's a marker interface, you don't have to implement any method.

Comment: It's Ok, i solved the problem. In fact the JSF managed bean is Serializable so it is trying to serialize the EJB instance which is not serializable since it contains an EntityManager. I added transient to that instance and that made the error disappear. Thanks for help.